# Clojure how to send some args to a function that is called as a symbol

Tags: clojure

What I'm trying to do is call a function from a map with some locally defined variables without expressing the whole variable in the call to the function.

For example, the following code works, :

```
(let [a [0 1 2]]
  (eval (list ({:fun 'count} :fun) a))) => 3
```

and this code works for a quoted 'a when it is globally defined:

```
(def a [0 1 2])
(eval (list ({:fun 'count} :fun) 'a))
```

but this code does not work:

```
(let [a [0 1 2]]
  (eval (list ({:fun 'count} :fun) 'a))) 
=> Unable to resolve symbol: a in this context
```

The first chunk is fine for small vectors like this one, but when I need to pass in a vector of several thousand items then the unquote "a" would cause it to throw an error for "Method too large" because the actual method sent to the machine is:

```
(let [a [0 1 2]]
  (eval (count [0 1 2]))
```

What is a simple way to execute a call to the function with the variable itself as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear why you are `eval`ing the *symbol* `'count`. Can't you just keep the *function* `count` in the map and call it as follows:

```
(let [a [0 1 2]] (({:fun count} :fun) a)) => 3
```

Then vector `a` can be any size you like.

---

- Don't use an `eval` where a macro will do.
- Don't use a macro where a function will do.

In retrospect, all you have done is defer compilation from when it is easy to when it is difficult.

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize I could do that. That simplifies the whole process. Thanks!